# how to interpret a probability predictions of a deep learning model that is an output of a sigmoid activation of last layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have trained a binary classification task (pos. vs. neg.) and have a `.h5` model. And I have external data (which was never used in training nor in the validation). There are 20 of samples overall belonging to both classes.

```
preds = model.predict(img)
y_classes = np.argmax(preds , axis=1)
```

The above code is supposed to calculate probability (preds) and class labels (0 or 1) if it were trained with *softmax* as the last output layer. But, *preds* is only a single number between [0;1] and *y_classes* is always 0.

To go back a little, the model was evaluated with mean AUC with the area being around 0.75.
I can see the probabilities of those 20 samples mostly (17) lie between 0 - 0.15, the rest are 0.74, 0.51 and 0.79.

How do I make a conclusion from this?

**EDIT:**
10 among 20 samples for testing the model belong to positive class, the other 10 belong to negative class. All 10 which belong to pos. class have very low prabability (0 - 0.15). 7 out 10 negative classes have the same low probability, only 3 being (0.74, 0.51 and 0.79).

The question: Why is the model predicting the samples with such a low probability even though its AUC was quite higher?

Answer (score 4):

the sigmoid activation function is used to generate probabilities in binary classification problems. in this case, the model output an array of probabilities with shape equal to the length of images to predict. we can retrieve the predicted class simply checking the probability score... if it's above 0.5 (this is a common practice but u can also change it according to your needs) the image belongs to the class 1 else it belongs to the class 0.

```
preds = model.predict(img) # (n_images, 1)
y_classes = ((pred > 0.5)+0).ravel() # (n_images,)
```

in case of sigmoid, your last output layer must be `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`

in the case of softmax (as you have just done), the predicted class are retrieved using argmax

```
preds = model.predict(img) # (n_images, n_class)
y_classes = np.argmax(preds , axis=1)  # (n_images,)
```

in case of softmax, your last output layer must be `Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')`

**WHY AUC IS NOT A GOOD METRIC**

The value of AUC can be misleading and can cause us sometimes to overestimate and sometimes to underestimate the actual performance of a model. The behavior of Average-Precision is more expressive in getting a flavor of how the model is doing because it is more sensible in distinguishing between a good and a very good model. Moreover, it is directly linked to precision: an indicator which is human-understandable Here a great reference about the topics which explains all you need: https://towardsdatascience.com/why-you-should-stop-using-the-roc-curve-a46a9adc728

Answer (score 0):

By using a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) as your activation function you are basically "compressing" the output of prior layers to a probability value from 0 to 1.

Softmax function is just taking a sequence of sigmoid functions, aggregates them and shows the ratio between a specific class probability and all aggregated probabilities for all classes.

For example: if I'm using a model to predict whether an image is an image of a banana, apple or grape, and my model recognizes that a certain image is 0.75 banana, 0.20 apple and 0.15 grape (Each probability is generated with a sigmoid function), my softmax layer will make this calculation:

banana: 0.75 / (0.75 + 0.20 + 0.15) = 0.6818 && apple: 0.20 / 1.1 = 0.1818 && grape: 0.15 / 1.1 = 0.1364.

As we can see, this model will classify this specific picture as a picture of a banana thanks to our softmax layer. Yet, in order to make this classification, it priorly used a series of sigmoid functions.

So if we finally reach to the point, I'd say that the interpretation of a sigmoid function output should be similar to the one that you'd make with a softmax layer, but while a softmax layer gives you the comparison between one class to another, a sigmoid function simply tells you how likely it is that this piece of information belongs to the positive class.

In order to make the final call and decide if a certain item does or doesn't belong to the positive class, you need to pick a threshold (not necessarily 0.5). Picking a threshold is the final step of your output interpretation. If you'd like to max the precision of your model, you will pick a high threshold, but if you'd like to max the recall of your model you can definitely pick a lower threshold.

I hope it answers your question, let me know if you'd like me to elaborate on anything as this answer is quite general.

Comment: Thanks for your your feedback. 1. Your probability distribution is wrong. 2. I am already aware of what the two functions mean. 3. 17 out of 20 samples show that the probability doesn't even reach 0.2 which means it is failing. Only 3 are over 0.5 (say, the threshold to assume is 0.5) which is say 15% accurate in terms of vague accuracy. How is it possible when mean AUC is aroun 0.75?